# TCP Connection Creation and Closing Event Hooking

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, tcpclient

What helper classes C# provides to monitor all TCP connection on an OS. A piece of Sample code would also be appreciated.

Note:
Original intent was to monitor this on Windows but would be nice to do the same on other os using .Net Core.

Comment: You would like to monitor tcp ip ports on a machine?

Comment: Yes,want to monitor the life of port i.e duration of port from creation to closing

Comment: I think you may be confusing a port with a socket (connection). A port is an address fragment, and does not have a state (like "closed"), whereas a socket can be in several states (such as "listening", "connected", "closed", etc). You can have multiple connected sockets on the same port (like a web server has many connected clients on port 80), but only one listening socket per port. So would you like to monitor all socket activity, or would you just like to monitor listening sockets that are bound to specific ports (i.e. from the moment they start listening until they stop listening)?

Comment: Windows All verions specially servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to monitor TCP Sockets on the machine, you can use System.Net.NetworkInformation.GetActiveTcpConnections which should give you a list of TCP connections and the current state of each. Which you can call on a regular timer to get updated states of the sockets.

I am more familiar with the Win32 APIs for this, such as GetTcpTable and the less documented GetTcpTableEx, the later also provides the process ID of the process that ownes the local end point. So the above might not give exactly what I believe it does :)

Of course if you need to be notified the very instant before or after a tcp socket is created or it's state changes, that unfortunately would require a kernel mode driver which cannot be written in .NET.

Comment: I know that `netstat -b` requires elevated privileges, so if `GetTcpTableEx(...)` provides the same functionality, then it might also require admin rights.

Comment: You don't need to be in kernel mode: Event trace for windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968803.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you really need an event based mechanism, event trace for windows is the way to go. Since you said it's only a preference :) you're best off writing this using the windows api (c/c++).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964766(v=vs.85).aspx

From .NET 3.5 onwards parts of the event trace are accessible via .NET using the System.Diagnostics.Eventing namespace. I understand that this has been improved in .NET 4.0. I haven't looked into this myself so I don't know whether TCP Connection detection is possible.

I know for sure that you can do what you want with windows api and ETW.